# Textbook recommendation request: Exercises to supplement Evans and Gariepy

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, textbook-recommendation

While a great book about measure theory and real analysis in $\mathbb R^n$, the only downside is the lack of exercises. Can anyone provide a good book to supplement it with exercises? I plan to use it for self study.

Comment: Have you given a look to _Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems_ (Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Fusco, and Diego Pallara), Oxford Mathematical Monographs? The first two-three chapters may be of interest to you and they contain (non-trivial) exercises.

Comment: Concerning Sobolev spaces, I would also recommend the well known book by Brezis, _Functional Analysis_, Springer.

Comment: I will check out the first one, seems interesting!

Comment: This is a very **good question** since it is really difficult to find a reasonable collection of problems in elementary geometric measure theory and Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look for a generic collection of problems in measure theory and functional analysis, I would highly recommend:

**A. Torchinsky,** *[Problems in real and functional analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=wB-jCgAAQBAJ).* [Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 166](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-166/). American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2015.
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=JOUR&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Torchinsky&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=Books&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=3443231)).

This is a great collection of problems with complete solutions.

However, if you are looking more for a collection of problems in geometric measure they and Sobolev spaces, as it is represented in the book by Evans and Gariepy, it is difficult to find one. However, the book

**W. P. Ziemer**, [**Weakly Differentiable Functions**. *Sobolev spaces and functions of bounded variation.*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1015-3).
Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 120. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1989.
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=CC&pg7=RVCN&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=ziemer&s5=weakly%20differentiable%20functions&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)).

presents material similar to that in the book by Evans and Gariepy and it includes many exercises. Unfortunately the exercises do not have solutions.

Comment: What a nice book the one by Torchinksy, I did not know it! It is a pity it does not have exercises on GMT. It reminds me somehow of the Costara-Popa (which is btw more on the functional analytic point of view). Thanks in any case for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Concerning Geometric measure theory and BV functions, I would recommend *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* (by Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Fusco, and Diego Pallara), Oxford Mathematical Monographs. The first two-three chapters may be of interest to you and they contain (non-trivial) exercises.

Concerning Sobolev spaces, I would also recommend the well known book by Brezis, *Functional Analysis*, Springer, at least for exercises concerning the one-dimensional case.

Comment: Brezis does not have exercises in Sobolev spaces except Sobolev spaces in dimension one.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Uh you are right, I thought it had problems also for multi-d case, but I got confused, you are right. Thanks!